# how to show array of parent and child Data as row in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, datatables, codeigniter-3

i am working in codeigniter and i need to show a list of destinations as row in datatables, like UK as Parent and London as Child destination.
i need to show them in datatable, i have created array of both parent and child data, but i am not able to understand, how to show them in datatable properly as each child destination row below their parent row.
something like wordpress parent and child category.

here is what i did as of now.

here is my controller

```
    public function fetch_destinations(){

  
    // POST data
    $postData = $this->input->post();

    // Get data
    $data = $this->tourismo->fetch_dest_nested($postData);

    echo json_encode($data);  

}
```

this is my model

```
    function fetch_dest_nested($postData=null)
   {
      $response = array();

         ## Read value
      $draw = $postData['draw'];
      $start = $postData['start'];
      $rowperpage = $postData['length']; // Rows display per page
      $columnIndex = $postData['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
      $columnName = $postData['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
      $columnSortOrder = $postData['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
      $searchValue = $postData['search']['value']; // Search value


      ## Search
      $search_arr = array();
      $searchQuery = "";
      if($searchValue != ''){
         $search_arr[] = " (name like '%".$searchValue."%' ) ";
      }

      if(count($search_arr) > 0){
         $searchQuery = implode(" and ",$search_arr);
      }
  
      ## Total number of records without filtering
       $this->db->set_dbprefix('');
       $this->db->select('count(*) as allcount');
       $records = $this->db->get('destinations')->result();
       $totalRecords = $records[0]->allcount;

       ## Total number of record with filtering
      $this->db->select('count(*) as allcount');
      if($searchQuery != '')
      $this->db->where($searchQuery);
      $records = $this->db->get('destinations')->result();
      $totalRecordwithFilter = $records[0]->allcount;

      //fetch records
      $this->db->select("*");
      if($searchQuery != '')
      $this->db->where($searchQuery);
      $this->db->where('level', 1);
      $this->db->order_by($columnName, $columnSortOrder);
      $this->db->limit($rowperpage, $start);
      $this->db->from("destinations");
      $q = $this->db->get();

      
      $final = array();
      if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {

               $this->db->select("*");
               $this->db->from("destinations");
               $this->db->where("parentid", $row->id);
               $q = $this->db->get();
               if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                  $row->children = $q->result();
               }
               array_push($final, $row);
            }
      }

   $data = array();

   foreach($final as $parentdest){

      $data[] = array(
         "id"=>$parentdest->id,
         "name"=>$parentdest->name,
         "slug"=>$parentdest->slug
       );
     
   }

      ## Response
      $response = array(
         "draw" => intval($draw),
         "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
         "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
         "aaData" => $data
      );

      return $response;

      

   }
```

this is my view

```
<table class="apitable table dt-table" id="destlist_table">
                 <thead>
                 <th>
                 Destination Id</th>
                 <th>Destination Name</th>
                <th>Destination Slug</th>
                 </thead>
               </table>
```

here is my jquery code for ajax request

```
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

       var destlistDataTable = $('#destlist_table').DataTable({
         'bDestroy': true,
         'processing': true,
         'serverSide': true,
         'serverMethod': 'post',
         "searching": true,
         "pageLength": 10,
         "order":[[0,'desc']],
         'ajax': {
            'url':'<?php echo admin_url('tourismo/tourismo/fetch_destinations'); ?>',
            'data': function(data){
            }
         },
         'columns': [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'slug' },
         ]
       });
    });
```

what i want is every child destination row should be just below its Parent destination row, i am just not able to understand how to work with this loop here.

this is the reference for what i want
[image]

Comment: Without seeing the raw data from `tourismo/tourismo/fetch_destinations` - or a similar set of data - I think this is a hard question to answer. One thing that sticks out though is that perhaps your data could be presented differently...? If you had a column for the country and then another for the city it might make more sense to your users, it would also aid sorting I think. Alternatively, child rows could be used?